# How to set maximum stack size for dart vm

Tags: dart

I cannot find an option related to stack size in `dart -v`, as of something like `--stack_size` in V8. Simply setting ulimit has no effect. This is the way I test.

```dart
foo(n){
  print(n);
  foo(n+1);
}

main(){
  foo(1);
}
```

**UPDATE:**

As of 2015/02/12, thread stack size is not configurable and defaults to (128 * kWordSize * KB) [see OSThread::GetMaxStackSize] [source][1](https://groups.google.com/a/dartlang.org/forum/#!topic/vm-dev/kmgPbqBSt54)

Comment: Evidently the Dart compiler doesn't do tail call optimization ;) - out of curiosity, how high does it go before it blows?

Comment: I think they will add the tail call optimization eventually, because ES6 standard includes it. Meanwhile, there are couple of pub packages for explicit tail call optimization.

Comment: @500 on my macbook pro the last number the above program shown in console is 25285.

Answer (score 0):

https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=8557#c2 says

```
Stack space for the main thread is not set by the VM, but by the OS on launch. ...
```

This answer https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/127615/40327 says a specific value can be passed but there is a default. I assume this is what Dart does, use the OS default

(Similar but for Windows https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686774(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: Thanks for reply. For C/C++, I used to use  `ulimit -S -s unlimited`  to increase stack size, if that is not enough, I would change the limit in /etc/security/limits.conf (linux). This is also one of the method mentioned in  the stackexchange post. I tried both smaller and bigger values by ulimit, however the above program still show the same last number. The dart vm stack size seems **independent** of the values.

Comment: Then my answer might be wrong. You could post a link to this SO question at https://groups.google.com/a/dartlang.org/forum/#!forum/vm-dev to increase visibility. My knowledge about this topic is only what my searching skills brought up ;-)